Playing audio by writing pcm data in flutter(like AudioTrack for Android)
I've just started writing android/ios application with Flutter.
I would like to feed 32bit float data continuously to play the audio like AndioTrack in Android.
Is there any suitable way on flutter?
I've tried "sound_stream" plugin but it seems to be in early development stage according to the explanation.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
